# Alfresco GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: out-of-memory, alfresco, heap-memory, memory-limit

I have still this problem , I read all the others forum posts about the problem but no one said how to fix, I run alfresco as a windows service on windows server. 
Here is my value data:

```
-Xms1G
-Xmx4G
-XX:MaxPermSize=1G
-XX:-DisableExplicitGC
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-Dalfresco.home=C:\Alfresco
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Alfresco\tomcat
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Alfresco\tomcat
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Alfresco\tomcat\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Alfresco\tomcat\conf\logging.properties
```

System ;

```
Processor : 3.40 GHz
RAM : 8.00 GB
System type : 64-bit
```

and here is a part of alfresco.log ;

```
00:05:29,189 ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 08170001 Wrapped Exception (with status template): GC overhead limit exceeded
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 08170001 Wrapped Exception (with status template): GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:422)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:452)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:491)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:268)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1877)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.property.PropertyTokenizer.<init>(PropertyTokenizer.java:15)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.setValue(MetaObject.java:108)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.applyPropertyMappings(FastResultSetHandler.java:224)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.getRowValue(FastResultSetHandler.java:196)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(FastResultSetHandler.java:145)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(FastResultSetHandler.java:124)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(FastResultSetHandler.java:98)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:55)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:120)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:94)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor341.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:338)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.select(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.select(SqlSessionTemplate.java:210)
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.node.ibatis.NodeDAOImpl.selectChildAssocs(NodeDAOImpl.java:1057)
    at org.alfresco.repo.domain.node.AbstractNodeDAOImpl.getChildAssocs(AbstractNodeDAOImpl.java:3403)
    at org.alfresco.repo.solr.SOLRTrackingComponentImpl.getNodesMetadata(SOLRTrackingComponentImpl.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.getNodesMetadata(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the JVM really took those increased memory settings?

Answer (score 2):

Check the size that you have set for JVM in alfresco.bat/alfresco.sh.

Increase 128 to 256 and 512 to 1024, if you have enough RAM available in your server then try again.

Comment: Here is my JVM settings:
`set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2G -Xmx4G -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -server`

Comment: Do you see the xmx value in your alfresco.log file? there should be a row near the end once Alfresco server starts with max memory setting. Not sure your JVM is picking up those values. Aside, what causes your memory issues? An action, bulk upload, usage?

Comment: Nope @Alch3mi5t , there is no xmx value in alfresco.log , and cause is that alfresco is running in real time , everyday approximate two hundred thousand documents (images) come to alfresco.

Comment: well, you should look for the xmx value (it's a standard log so you should have it in your log, once alfresco is starting), or just search for it in the past logs when alfresco was started last time. For search purposes, maybe you should focus on a row with: 7070 it's the jetty default port, you should find the xmx value a couple of rows above (or beneath, really not sure atm). That value will confirm you have the correct parameters in your jvm. Still, 200k documents every day is quite a number, so maybe you should pump up that RAM, probably 8GB is not enough.